# How to add piece-wise linear constraint in pyomo

Tags: pyomo

In a task allocation problem, let's assume:

1. we need to allocate 4 tasks to 4 days.
2. There is only one worker and has to work at most 8 hours a day.
3. We want to minimize the total working time.
4. We can bundle tasks and save time **in one day**. The number of hours needed is

> 0 task --> 0 hours
>
> 1 task --> 6 hours
>
> 2 task --> 8 hours

An illustration for the *# of Tasks* V.S. *# of Hours needed*:

[image]

Blue dashed line: y = 6*n

Black line: Actual time = min(6*n, 6 + 2 * (n - 1))

Red line: Daily limit

This computation function (for the black line) can be defined in Python as

```
def compute_hours(n):
    return min(6*n, 6 + 2 * (n - 1))
```

Using the function defined above in the constraint setting, `pyomo` give errors when I put this in my constraint list.

```
> File "<ipython-input-69-57dbda13a71f>", line 23, in compute_hours
>     return min(6*n, 6 + 2 * (n - 1))   File "pyomo\core\expr\logical_expr.pyx", line 183, in
> pyomo.core.expr.logical_expr.InequalityExpression.__bool__
> pyomo.common.errors.PyomoException: Cannot convert non-constant
> expression to bool. This error is usually caused by using an
> expression in a boolean context such as an if statement. For example, 
>     m.x = Var()
>     if m.x <= 0:
>         ... would cause this exception.
```

The error is also easy to reproduce using the following sample code:

```
# Allocating tasks to days

from pyomo.environ import *
import pandas as pd

m = ConcreteModel()

# We have 4 tasks in total. Each cost 6 hours
m.TASKS = ('task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4')

# There are 4 days to allocate to
m.DAYS = (1, 2, 3, 4)

# Hours per task
HOURS_PER_TASK = 6


def compute_hours(n):
    return min(6*n, 6 + 2 * (n - 1))

# for x in range(0, 4):
#     print(x, compute_hours(x))

# Create a decision array for the allocation
m.ALLOCATION = Var(m.TASKS, m.DAYS, domain=Binary)

# Create an array for total hours computation
m.TOTAL_HOURS = Var(m.DAYS, domain=Integers)

# minimize the number of days that are allocated tasks
m.OBJ = Objective(expr=sum([m.TOTAL_HOURS[day] for day in m.DAYS]), sense=minimize)

m.c = ConstraintList()

# One task is done once only in all days
for task in m.TASKS:
    m.c.add(sum([m.ALLOCATION[task, day] for day in m.DAYS]) == 1)

# Compute Total hours a day
for day in m.DAYS:
    m.c.add(sum([m.ALLOCATION[task, day] for task in m.TASKS])*HOURS_PER_TASK == m.TOTAL_HOURS[day])
    # The following computation does not work
    #m.c.add(compute_hours(sum([m.ALLOCATION[task, day] for task in m.TASKS])*HOURS_PER_TASK) == m.TOTAL_HOURS[day])


# Add max working hours per day
for day in m.DAYS:
    m.c.add(m.TOTAL_HOURS[day] <= 8)

SolverFactory('glpk').solve(m).write()

# Show the results
SCHEDULE_df = pd.DataFrame(index = m.TASKS, columns= m.DAYS)
SCHEDULE_HOURS_df = pd.DataFrame(index = m.TASKS, columns= m.DAYS)

for i in m.TASKS:
    for j in m.DAYS:
        SCHEDULE_df.loc[i,j] = m.ALLOCATION[i,j]()

print('------------------------------------------')
print('ALLOCATION:')
print(SCHEDULE_df)

print('------------------------------------------')
print('Total hours per day:')
print(m.TOTAL_HOURS.get_values())
print('Total hours:')
print(value(m.OBJ))
```

This example can still give results if we assume each task always takes 6 hours.

```
------------------------------------------
ALLOCATION:
       1  2  3  4
task1  1  0  0  0
task2  0  1  0  0
task3  0  0  1  0
task4  0  0  0  1
------------------------------------------
Total hours per day:
{1: 6.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 6.0, 4: 6.0}
Total hours:
24.0
```

If we can realize the bundling, then this worker only needs to work for two days with workload 8 hours/day (instead of working 6 hours/day for 4 days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John.

`Pyomo` got a [Piecewise Linear Expression](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Expressions.html#piecewise-linear-expressions) for these cases. (`kernel` layer also got the [Piecewise Function Library](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/library_reference/kernel/piecewise/index.html))

In your case, it is easy, in fact, to use the `Piecewise` in `Pyomo`.

You need to create an helper variable with the same index than `m.TOTAL_HOURS` (requested by `pyomo`), let's call it `m.TASK_PER_DAY` that will account for the number of task assignned for each day. This `TASK_PER_DAY` var will be then computed (constrained) with `m.ALLOCATION` using the summation of task each day (Similar as you try to constraint). Then, you can use the `pyomo` `Piecewise` to computed the `TOTAL_HOURS` depending upon `TASK_PER_DAY`

**Edit:** Further explanation on `pw_pts` and `f_rule`, that are the source of error in modelung in `Piecewise`.
`pw_pts` are the break points (independent values, domain) in the `Piecewise`. `f_rule` is the known value at given points `pw_pts`. This may be a function or a couple of points. If you want to linearly interpolate the points (as your image) you just need to define such points `pw_pts=[0,1,2,3,...]` and `f_rule=[0,6,8,10,...]`, but for [constant piecewise functions](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiecewiseConstantFunction.html) you need to specify the same point twice in order to ensure that for domain points, the piecewise returns the same value as in a step function. In your modeling, since variable are `integers`, there is not problem, but is better to clear the issue.

```
m.TASK_PER_DAY = Var(m.DAYS, domain=Integers)
m.PIECEWISE_DAILY_HOURS = Piecewise(
    m.DAYS,
    m.TOTAL_HOURS,
    m.TASK_PER_DAY,
    pw_pts=[0,1,2,3],
    f_rule=[0,6,8,10],
    pw_repn='SOS2',
    pw_constr_type='EQ',
    unbounded_domain_var=True
)
#Constraining TASK_PER_DAY
def Assign_Task(model, day):
    return model.TASK_PER_DAY[day] == sum(model.ALLOCATION[task,day] for task in model.TASKS)
m.assign_task = Constraint(m.DAYS, rule=Assign_Task)
```

In this Approach you're not constraining the day to perform the task, therefore, the assignned day may be any pair of days, but each day certainly got 2 task per day. If you want to contraint the model to perform the task as soon (early days) as possible, you need to add that new constraint.

The following code can reproduce the desired output:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

#Sets
# We have 4 tasks in total. Each cost 6 hours
m.TASKS = ('task1', 'task2', 'task3', 'task4')
# There are 4 days to allocate to
m.DAYS = (1, 2, 3, 4)
# Hours per task
HOURS_PER_TASK = 6

#Variables
# Create a decision array for the allocation
m.ALLOCATION = pyo.Var(m.TASKS, m.DAYS, domain=Binary)
m.TOTAL_HOURS = pyo.Var(m.DAYS, domain=Integers)
m.TASK_PER_DAY = pyo.Var(m.DAYS, domain=Integers)

#Piecewise
m.PIECEWISE_DAILY_HOURS = pyo.Piecewise(
    m.DAYS,
    m.TOTAL_HOURS,
    m.TASK_PER_DAY,
    pw_pts=[0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3],
    f_rule=[0,0,6,6,8,8,10,10],
    pw_repn='SOS2',
    pw_constr_type='EQ',
    unbounded_domain_var=True
)

#Objective
# minimize the number of days that are allocated tasks
m.OBJ = pyo.Objective(expr=sum([m.TOTAL_HOURS[day] for day in m.DAYS]), sense=minimize)

m.c = pyo.ConstraintList()

# One task is done once only in all days
for task in m.TASKS:
    m.c.add(sum([m.ALLOCATION[task, day] for day in m.DAYS]) == 1)

#Compute the number of tasks per day
def Assign_Task(model, day):
    return model.TASK_PER_DAY[day] == sum(model.ALLOCATION[task,day] for task in model.TASKS)

m.assign_task = pyo.Constraint(m.DAYS, rule=Assign_Task)

# Add max working hours per day
for day in m.DAYS:
    m.c.add(m.TOTAL_HOURS[day] <= 8)

pyo.SolverFactory('gurobi').solve(m, tee=True)
```

Then the solution is reduced to 16 hours.

```
>>>m.OBJ()
16.0
>>>m.TOTAL_HOURS.display()
TOTAL_HOURS : Size=4, Index=TOTAL_HOURS_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      1 :  None :  -0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      2 :  None :   8.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      3 :  None :  -0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      4 :  None :   8.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
>>>m.TASK_PER_DAY.display()
TASK_PER_DAY : Size=4, Index=TASK_PER_DAY_index
    Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
      1 :  None :   0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      2 :  None :   2.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      3 :  None :   0.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
      4 :  None :   2.0 :  None : False : False : Integers
>>>m.ALLOCATION.display()
ALLOCATION : Size=16, Index=ALLOCATION_index
    Key          : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
    ('task1', 1) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task1', 2) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task1', 3) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task1', 4) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task2', 1) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task2', 2) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task2', 3) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task2', 4) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task3', 1) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task3', 2) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task3', 3) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task3', 4) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task4', 1) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task4', 2) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task4', 3) :     0 :  -0.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
    ('task4', 4) :     0 :   1.0 :     1 : False : False : Binary
```

Comment: Thank you very much:)  BTW, do you know any open source solver can also support SOS level 2 constraints? I tested `glpk` and it does not work.

Comment: No, sorry. But if you change the `Piecewise` arg to `pw_repn='DCC'`(check the other options in the Pyomo documentation) you can use `glpk`

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks.